# MySQL match against Boolean Mode search - apostrophe

Tags: mysql, boolean, boolean-search

I'm using a match against query in boolean mode to create a search feature.
The search works, and returns results how I would expect them to, except that there is one problem with words with apostrophes in them.

If there is a word saved on the database with an apostrophe in it (**pirate's** for example) and you search for the word with the apostrophe in it, or without the end of the word (**pirate's** or **pirate** for example) it returns results, however if i search the word without the apostrophe (**pirates**) it returns no results.

I've tried changing the record in the database to be escaped and not escaped, and I can't seem to find a way to fix it.

I have also spend a while searching for simular answers, but none have the same problem as this, they seem to be more about returning results for a search without the apostrophe **and** the s.

*My query is:*

```
SELECT * FROM flyer WHERE MATCH(band, venue, promoter) AGAINST('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: because i'm using php to perform the mysql query, and thought that people knowledgeable about php would be able to help with the mysql. Is this wrong?

Comment: Yes. Your question is in reference to MySQL. Just because you're *using* one technology, that doesn't mean your question is relevant to that technology. For example, you could be using a GUI such as MySQL Administrator to do what you're doing, but you wouldn't tag "MySQL Administrator" because the question refers to MySQL, not the tool being used.

Comment: No problem, just a heads-up. Some people get upset over things like that.

Comment: What you provided isn't the actual query that's being sent to mySQL because it still has your PHP variable; What does your query look like when you var_dump() it? Does it work correctly in phpMyAdmin (outside of PHP)? I'm learning boolean searching right now and have tried searches with apostrophes - and without - on varchar fields and have received results on each query.